# Flutter: ListView inside Row gives me Right Overflowed

Tags: flutter

I wanted to fix my `Icon Container` and then make the `Card Container` scrollable. However, I am getting `Right Overflow` error. I think it is because of the `Icon Container`'s width. How can I make my icons fixed in position and make ListView vertically scrollable at the same time?

```
return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 150,
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 20,
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('hello');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 150,
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Text('hello'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 150,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

----- Edit

So the result of the code above is like this. What I want to do is that

- IconButton in the fix place.
- Cards will be horizontally scrollable.

without the `Right Overflow` warning.

[image]

Comment: In your code you have define scroll direction to be horizontal, improve your question, and write clearly what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Please Improve your submitted code too, so that we can find the issue.

Comment: Sorry guys. I thought the picture was included. I just edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to Wrap second container with Expanded:

```
return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 150,
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 20,
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('hello');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(child:
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 150,
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Text('hello'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 150,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),),
        ),
      ],
    );
```